# Shape of a Hanging Rope Using Calculus of Variations (General Case)

Tags: optimization, physics, calculus-of-variations

Given that the rope with uniformly distributed mass is attached to two points (important: the points do not have to be at the same height). How to derive the shape of such rope using calculus of variations? I guess, the total potential energy has to be minimal.
Just in case, potential energy of a point is defined as $mgh$, where $g$ is the gravitational acceleration, $m$ is the mass and $h$ is the height. Potential energy of an arbitrary shape is the same $mgh$, where $H$ is the height of its center of mass.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenary

Comment: @joriki I can derive this without Wikipedia. The question is how to derive this formula using variational approach.

Comment: [Derive it for points at the same height](http://www.dmf.unicatt.it/divulgazione/mateott/catenaria/catenary/catenary.htm) and then argue that every part of the rope optimizes the subproblem for that part, hence the same shape must also solve the problem with different heights.

Comment: A related recent question: [Euler-Lagrange equation with Lagrange multipliers](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3498723).